# Como impedir que minha aplicação firebase seja usada em outros sites?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Como impedir que outras pessoas peguem esse código do meu site e usem em outros, ou como fazer que só funcione no meu?

```
var config = {
      apiKey: 'your-api-key',
      authDomain: 'your-auth-domain',
      databaseURL: 'your-database-url',
      storageBucket: 'your-storage-bucket'
    };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

(editado)
Tem como eu ter um servidor só para usar esse codigo do firebase mas usar a aplicação em outro site?

Comment: Não usando isto no JS do navegador?

Comment: Preciso pois não tenho acesso ao servidor.

Comment: Então esquece..

Comment: CORS com lista de autorização de quais domínios você quer aceitar acesso. Ainda assim, credenciais e chaves de autorização não devem nunca estar presentes direto no JavaScript.

Comment: @Haffy Não use o campo de edição para alterar a intenção da pergunta, pois corre o risco de invalidar as respostas já dadas. Em vez disso, faça outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A maior questão neste ponto é permitir alguém não autenticado realize a leitura/escrita das informações no seu banco de dados. por padrão o Firebase bloqueia isto.

Se você for em `Menu -> DataBase -> Rules` verá o seguinte:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Desta forma usuários não autenticados não podem consumir informações.

Da uma olhada nesse: [Quickstart de Segurança do Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

É possível obfuscar o código com vários obfuscadores e compressores de JavaScript para impedir que o código seja legível ou editável, porém o mais preciso é "reforçar" o código, o que ainda não tem alguma ferramenta desenvolvida ainda. Poderia ser basicamente feita uma condição assim para checar se o domínio da página é o verdadeiro:

```
var i = location.href.indexOf('//') + 2,
    sub = location.href.substring(i,
                       (location.href.substring(i).indexOf('/') + i) || null
);

sub === "www.example.com" || sub === "example.com";
```

, que não é suficiente e difícil de aplicar várias vezes em um projeto, porém.

## JScrambler

O JScrambler é um obfuscador online de JavaScript e tem opção para fazer o script funcionar em um domínio específico (deve ser muito simples na versão básica), que tem uma versão [antiga](https://jscrambler.com/en/) e uma versão [nova](https://app.jscrambler.com). A versão nova não é gratuita e parece uma base melhor, enquanto a versão antiga é gratuita e não tem quase nenhum recurso de obfuscação. Não tenho como comprovar muito a versão paga já que nunca comprei – ele tem um exemplo de demostra, por sorte.

---

Graças à interpretadores de fácil uso em JavaScript pode ser criada alguma ferramenta no futuro, ou próximo daqui.